# split gridlayout to can not draw in paint app kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

I designed this program
python code:

```
from random import random
from kivymd.app import MDApp as App
from kivymd.uix.widget import MDWidget as Widget
from kivy.graphics import Ellipse, Color, Line
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class Main(Screen):
    draw = ObjectProperty(None)

class About(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    mgr = ObjectProperty(None)

    def cleaner(self):
        self.mgr.draw.clean()
    def color(self,color):
        MyPaintWidget.color = color


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    color = (0,0,0,1)

    def clean(self):
        self.canvas.clear()
    
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        # self.rect.pos = touch.pos
        color = self.color
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color)
            d = 10
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y),width = 5)
    def on_touch_up(self,touch):
        with self.canvas:
            d = 10
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        # self.rect.pos = touch.pos
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
        

#main_style = Builder.load_file("ms_paint.kv")

class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file("ms_paint.kv")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
#:import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

Manager:
    mgr: sc_mgr
    Main:
        id: sc_mgr
    About:

<MyPaintWidget>:
    on_touch_down: self.on_touch_down
    on_touch_move: self.on_touch_move

<Main>:
    name: "main"
    draw: main_draw
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MyPaintWidget:
            id: main_draw
            size_hint: 1, 0.9

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            cols: 7
            padding: 10

            #Button:
                #text: "About"
                #on_press:
                    #root.manager.current= "about"
                    #root.manager.transition.direction= "left"
            
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "eraser-variant"
                on_press: root.manager.cleaner()
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "circle"
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                icon_color: (0,0,0,1)
                on_press: root.manager.color((0,0,0,1))
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "circle"
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                icon_color: get_color_from_hex("#ff0000")
                on_press: root.manager.color((255,0,0,1))
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "circle"
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                icon_color: get_color_from_hex("#00ff00")
                on_press: root.manager.color((0,255,0,1))
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "circle"
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                icon_color: get_color_from_hex("#0000ff")
                on_press: root.manager.color((0,0,255,1))




<About>:
    name: "about"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: 10

        Label:
            size_hint: 1, 0.9
            text: "This is a free and open source paint app, made by a teacher of HamRuyesh community."

        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.9
            text:"Back to Main"
            on_press:
                root.manager.current= "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction= "right"
```

My problem is that I do not want to draw a line in the bottom bar, which is a grid layout, and I just want to be able to draw from that part. please guide me.
..........................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`StencilView`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.stencilview.html) to limit the drawing area.

Thus You might change the `MyPaintWidget(Widget)` as

```py
class MyPaintWidget(BoxLayout, StencilView):
```